# Custom pipeline for Cordova social auth

Tags: python, django, cordova, pipeline, python-social-auth

I need two distinct login processes in my django server.

- Login for website users (I already have this)
- Login for app users - Cordova InAppBrowser

The login pipeline for app users must also generate a token and return it to the Cordova app. How should I go about creating a parallel pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have two types of users in your app:

```
1. User
2. CordovaUser
```

You need two different links for two different users and somehow you should know in the pipeline that one of them is `CordovaUser`.

First, in your settings, do this:

```
FIELDS_STORED_IN_SESSION = ['user_type']
```

then the links will look like this:

```
1. <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}">Login as User</a>
2. <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?user_type=cordova">Login as CordovaUser</a>
```

then customize `create_user` to look something like this:

```
def create_user(strategy, details, user=None, *args, **kwargs):
    if user:
        return {'is_new': False}

    fields = dict((name, kwargs.get(name) or details.get(name))
              for name in strategy.setting('USER_FIELDS',
                                           USER_FIELDS))
    if not fields:
        return

    user_type = strategy.session_get('type')

    if user_type != 'cordova':
        return {
            'is_new': True,
            'user': strategy.create_user(**fields)
        }
    else:
        return {
            'is_new': True,
            'user': create_cordova_user(**fields)
        }
```

then, create that `create_cordova_user` method and you are done.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer!!!  One more thing. How do I return a token for the cordova user? I could append the token to the redirect url as a `GET` parameter. How should I specify the redirect?

Comment: @Ajoy, do you mean `access_token` of a user? If so, you can get it like so: `user.social_auth.get(provider='facebook').access_token`. If no, please can you explain what exactly it is that you are trying to do?

Comment: Not that. The server will generate a token. But how will I pass it to the cordova app? I read somewhere that it could be attached to the success callback, so that the Cordova browser can fetch the token created by the server.

Comment: @Ajoy you should write another question about that. I would really love to help but I don't know anything about Cordova.

Comment: I guess you are right. That should be a different question.